# I have a Function for update password screen now i want to add same function for different screen with some different parameters

Tags: oracle, plsql

Problem is that when i am tyring to make my funtion having 2 different statements during compile it happen error

This is my whole function to update password but it have errors during compile

```
create or replace FUNCTION updatePassword(
CurrentP VARCHAR2,
NewPwd VARCHAR2,
StudentId number)
RETURN number

    is
        getCount number :=0;

    BEGIN
        Select count(*) into getCount from users where student_id=StudentId and Password=md5(CurrentP);
        if getCount = 1
        then 
        update users set Password=md5(NewPwd) where student_id=StudentId and Password=md5(CurrentP);
      insert into users_log(Passwords,student_id,updated_by,action) values(md5(CurrentP),StudentId,StudentId,'Change');
        else
        getCount := 0;
        end if;
    RETURN getCount;
    END;
```

below is for same action  for another screen but happen error during compile image is provided

[image]

```
    DECLARE
    NazimId number;
    BEGIN
        Select count(*) into getCount from nazim_login where nazim_id=NazimId and Password=md5(CurrentP);
        if getCount = 1
        then 
        update nazim_login set Password=md5(NewPwd) where nazim_id=NazimId and Password=md5(CurrentP);
      insert into nazim_password_log(Passwords,nazim_id,updated_by,action) values(md5(CurrentP),NazimId,NazimId,'Change');
        else
        getCount := 0;
        end if;
    RETURN getCount;
    END;


BEGIN
        Select count(*) into getCount from users where student_id=StudentId and Password=md5(CurrentP);
        if getCount = 1
        then 
        update users set Password=md5(NewPwd) where student_id=StudentId and Password=md5(CurrentP);
      insert into users_log(Passwords,student_id,updated_by,action) values(md5(CurrentP),StudentId,StudentId,'Change');
        else
        getCount := 0;
        end if;
    RETURN getCount;
    END;
```

below is for same action  for another screen but happen error during compile

```
DECLARE
    NazimId number;
    BEGIN
        Select count(*) into getCount from nazim_login where nazim_id=NazimId and Password=md5(CurrentP);
        if getCount = 1
        then 
        update nazim_login set Password=md5(NewPwd) where nazim_id=NazimId and Password=md5(CurrentP);
      insert into nazim_password_log(Passwords,nazim_id,updated_by,action) values(md5(CurrentP),NazimId,NazimId,'Change');
        else
        getCount := 0;
        end if;
    RETURN getCount;
    END;
```

compile function with both begin and end statements

Comment: Brother i have attached above image of error

Comment: @HoneyBadger  check above attached link bro

Comment: Please don't paste pictures, provide the error message as text

Comment: Nobody can read your error screen shot.  Please edit the question, and paste in as text.  Thanks.